# Java Thread stopping execution where it shouldn't be

Tags: java, blocking, multithreading

I am writing a content distribution network in java. I have a Link class to manage sockets between two nodes in the system. There are two programs, RouterNode and DiscoveryNode.

When a router node starts up, the first thing it does is try to initialize a connection to the discovery node:

```
public RouterNode(int num)
{
    myNumber = num;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        discoveryServer = new Socket("MONDAY-PC", 60111);
        myServerLink = new Link(this, discoveryServer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Socket could not be opened. Node terminating.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

There is more to the constructor, but my problem keeps my program from getting past this try block.

The constructor of the link class (called on the line 'myServerLink = new Link(this, discoveryServer); ) looks as such:

```
public Link(Node n, Socket s)
{
    parentNode = n;
    regSocket = s;
    try {
        out =  new DataOutputStream(regSocket.getOutputStream());
        in = new DataInputStream(regSocket.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Data Streams could not be created on the link.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    new Thread(new LinkListenerThread(this, in)).run();
}
```

where the last line of this constructor starts a new thread that is designed to listen on the socket for incoming messages that are being passed.

The run() method in LinkListenerThread stars as follows:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    byte[] message;     

    System.out.println("Link now active and running.");
    while(!done)
    {
        System.out.println("attempting to read from socket...");

        try {

            // read now many bytes the following message will be
            byte[] messageLengthBytes = new byte[4];
            in.read(messageLengthBytes, 0, 4);
```

My problem is that once I instantiate the link from the router node, it's execution stops from what seems to be the LinkListenerThread blocking it when it calls in.read(). This listener is running on a separate thread so I am not sure if this is actually something strange with threads, or it is just an example of my lack of experience with them.

I have another instance in my program where I am reading on a separate thread

Could this be caused because the node classes aren't explicitly implementing runnable and therefore are not on their own threads?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: I have made the Node classes implement Runnable and starting them on their own threads, but it still locks up when the in.read() is called;

Comment: this should be moved to stackoverflow

Comment: also, normally if you want to learn threads you'd be better off with a program that functions in a simpler way..  You also should probably include full files.. So could even find simple versions of your program that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: haven't done java in ages, and hardly did threads, but maybe "in" has to be a thread? (if that makes sense) if you don't want "in" as a thread, then "in" has to complete in order to continue, so you should do some printlns to find out where "in" - in.read(..), is getting stuck

Comment: I talked to some friends as well and it turns out it was due to my inexperience with threads in java. The problem was pretty much fixed by me starting execution of the thread with .start() instead of .run()

And sorry for the misplaced question: wasn't even paying attention to where I posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You intend to start a thread by calling `Thread.run()` method instead of `Thread.start()`. And this makes your program single-threaded, then the I/O ops block the only thread(the main thread) in the try-catch clause if there is no data coming in or the while loop never ends.

Just use Thread.start() to start a thread can fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved by using .start() instead of .run()

It all boiled down to a misunderstanding of how to instantiate threads in java.